# Adding an iframe with a custom protocol causes IE to navigate to the iframe source

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

This one is so simple there must be a solution.

I create a [jsFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/cNj7E/).

the code is:

```
$(function(){
    $('<iframe>').attr('src', 'xyz://test').appendTo('body');
});
```

When the iframe gets appended, IE then navigates to the src. I tested in both IE9 and IE10. This does not happen in Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

It only happens when using a custom protocol such as xyz:// instead of http://.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You means show the source code in the iframe instead of calling an external app to handle the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx

> Application Protocols
>
> In contrast to Pluggable Protocols, Application Protocols are much
>   simpler. Rather than returning content to the browser, they simply
>   enable the browser (or another program like a word processor or PDF
>   reader) to launch a program, passing the requested URL to that
>   program. Common examples of Application Protocols include the
>   mailto:[1] news:, and onenote: protocols.

Comment: This did help quite a lot, thank you! I will mark your answer to accepted, but then post a second answer with more detail about the solution we ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has a link to the MSDN article that explains IE's behavior. In short, the article explains that there is no way to test for a custom protocol that is not installed.

In most browsers, an uninstalled protocol used as the source of an iframe will silently fail inside the iframe. This failure can be observed and taken as an indication that the protocol is not installed.

In IE however, the iframe will redirect the parent browser window to the failed protocol address even though the protocol was used as an iframe src, and not a link that was clicked on.

To address this we had to setup a server-side component that communicates with the installed application.

In IE, we always show the install instructions, and when they install the software the server-side component signals the browser to set a cookie or local storage value indicating that the software is installed.

This works for most cases, but not all. It would still fail if the person uninstalled the software. Also if they clear out cookies or local storage, then they will be asked to install the software again even though it is already installed.

Comment: In Win 8, IE 10+, you can use the msLaunchUri. Quote from above article: 

Instead use the msLaunchUri api to launch a protocol, like so:

`navigator.msLaunchUri('skype:123456', function(){alert('success');}, function(){alert('failed');} ); `

If the protocol is not installed, the failure callback will fire. Otherwise, the protocol will launch and the success callback will fire.